# Rounding to 2 decimal places causing inaccuracies

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-logic

My form allows the user to enter either a net amount or a gross amount.
Where net is entered, system caculates tax and gross.
Where gross is entered, system calculates net and tax.
If I enter a gross of 3.99 (a common type of price), it calculates to Net 3.33. tax 0.67. All of these values are stored in a database.
Adding the 2 back together, the price has now gone up to £4.00.
I have tried various permutations of Decimal.Round, but it makes no difference. If I always round up - the gross price goes up, if I always round down, the gross price goes down. The error is obviously with rounding, and the fact that the data is stored in SQL as Decimal(10,2).
Maybe the simplest solution would be to stop saving the calculated tax figure, but calculate it on the fly each time it is displayed.

Comment: the only real way round it is to not round it at all and only show rounded values to the user

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the solution seems pretty simple. When the user enters 3.99 you calculate the tax to be 0.67 (after rounding). Then simply calculate the net as gross - tax (i.e. 3.99 - 0.67 = 3.32). Save the post-rounded tax (i.e. 0.67) and the net calculated by subtracting. That way net + tax will always equal gross.

Comment: You are missing something Craig - the user could have entered the net amount instead. Maybe I have to make a record in the database as to which field was entered by the user, as it is important that this value is not changed (unless input has changed).